# How to use return in addEventListener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I use include login page in header of my site and when I use `onSubmit="return login();"` not working this function how can get true or false with this code:

```
document.getElementById("loginform").addEventListener("submit", login);
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking or what your problem is. And you asking how to cancel the event with addEventListener?

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("loginform").addEventListener("submit", login());
```

I thing you're missing () in the second parameter. If you don't have a function for the login make the function inside the second param

Comment: That would call `login` **immediately** and try to assign its return value as an event handler.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("loginform").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  if("Your Desired Conditions") {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  else{
      function(e){ return true; }  
  }
});
```